# Django, Where are the comments tables created?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

When using Django's built in comment package, where is the table created when the database is synced? The model doesn't seem to be in the models.py file.

I seem to be very confused trying to implement this. I found some tutorials online but nonw of them seem to help and I can't get anything to work.
Anyone have any tips? Can anyone explain how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`django.contrib.comments` is a reusable app packaged with Django. Reusable (sometimes called 3rd party, whether or not they are) apps have their own models.py, urls.py, etc. So if you'd like to look at a model from the `comments` package, browse your Django source directory. On Ubuntu, that would be something like `ls /usr/lib/python2.6/django/contrib/comments`.

When the sync command is run, it goes through all of the apps in your `INSTALLED_APPS` list in your project's `settings.py`, and uses their `models.py` files to generate database schema.

Though reusable apps can be a little confusing (especially overriding templates!) they allow for your code base to be way more modular.

Comment: You seem to understand this quite well.. quick question for you if you don't mind.. i got a {% get_comment_count for ..... etc} to work.. but it says there are 0 comments when i specifically went back to the model and added an instance... what is it counting, and based on what?

Comment: When you say you added an instance, do you mean you created and saved a `Post` model instance, or some other instance you'd like to attach comments to? Once you've done that, you need to actually attach a comment. If you look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/models/ you can see that, internally, the a `Comment` model has a foreign key to whatever instance you attach it to. Anyway, you can either create and attach programmatically (silly) or use the included template tags to show a comment form and add new comments.

Comment: Oh, and if this wasn't clear, the count is over the reverse of those foreign key relations.

Answer (score 1):

If you have things configured correctly you will see:

```
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_site
Creating table django_comments
Creating table django_comment_flags
```

Also make sure you have SQLite(assuming you are using sqlite) installed and have added the `django.contrib.comments` to your INSTALLED_APPS